# Click disabled with jquery panzoom

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery.panzoom

I'm using a jquery plugin that allows zooming with mousewheel (i'm using it for mobile, to allow pinch zooming on a pdf) 
and I used this code

```
(function() {
    var $section = $('#section');
    var $panzoom = $section.find('.panzoom').panzoom();
    $panzoom.parent().on('mousewheel.focal', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var delta = e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
        var zoomOut = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
        $panzoom.panzoom('zoom', zoomOut, {
            animate: false,
            focal: e
        });
    });
})();
```

But since I added the zooming on the element, the click event isn't triggered anymore :

```
 $("#section").click(function(e) {
    //something ...
    }
```

Are there a way to enable the click and the zooming (on mobile) on the same element?

Comment: did you tried HammerJS library?

Comment: How do you suggest using HammerJS? as it only provides events not zooming like panzoom? Or should I use both?

Comment: Just check on their website, and don't use both at a same time it may messes up everything.

Comment: Thanks! despite that I was asking about panzoom and you answered with check HammerJS website.